# CSOM And FieldURLValue Error

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server, client-object-model

I am trying to set a URL Field to update the Description and every time i run this ClientSide (via Powershell) I get the following error

> Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid URL: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue

Basically what I'm trying to do is to set the URL to a Folder in a Document Library for a Specific User

The List will show

```
Users Name

Dept

Team

Document Library URL
```

Currently it shows it all correctly however its not that nice to see a huge URL in the Document Library URL field hence I want to Update it to show the Description which should show "User's Documents"

Easy done on Server Side and I have it Working on Server Side - However I would like to set this Client Side

So an example is

```
Ryan

IT

SharePoint

Http://SP.Ryan.Test/sites/IT/SharePoint/Ryan


$url = $item["Document_x0020_Url"].url
$ofldurl= new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue
$ofldurl.URL = $url
$ofldurl.Description = $item["Title"]+"'s"+" "+"Documents"
$item["Document_x0020_Url"] = $ofldurl
$item.update()
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

I have double Checked and the URL is Set correctly in the Class (or at least it seems it to me) below is the output from the `FieldURLValue` Variable I had Created

```
Url

http://SP.Ryan.Test/sites/IT/SharePoint/Ryan              

Description 

Ryan's Documents
```

> TypeId
>
> {fa8b44af-7b43-43f2-904a-bd319497011e}

Can Anyone see why this is not working at all or is this just me having a bad day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've analyzed the requests sent by your PowerShell snippet and an equivalent version sent by "native" managed client object modell by [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). As far as I see, the difference is caused by the way PS handles (casts) objects in the background.

I found, that this version does what you need:

```
ofldurl= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue
$url = $item["Document_x0020_Url"].Url
$ofldurl.Description = $item["Title"]+"'s"+" "+"Documents"
$ofldurl.Url = $url
$item["Document_x0020_Url"] = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue]$ofldurl
$item.Update()
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Thank You For this - Cannot believe that is was something so simple